# Getting Error on Update React-Admin version update

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am using react-admin in my project and using the npm package of react-admin version 3.16.6
but now I want to update the react-admin of the latest version 4.16.3.
After updating to version 4.16.3, when building the project, I am getting the below error.

./node_modules/@mui/material/Tooltip/Tooltip.js
Cannot find module: 'react/jsx-runtime'.

whereas it is internally used by react-admin so I can't install that.

how to resolve that issue?

Comment: What version of React are you using? This looks like an error you get when using a React version that's too old... Also, did you upgrade to Material UI v5 as mentioned in the [upgrade guide](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Upgrade.html)?